# How to remove the newline after xml declaration by Python ElementTree?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am writing a xml to a string, here's my code to include the declaration

```
updatedxml = ET.tostring(root, encoding="utf8", method="xml").decode()
```

Output (Newline is added after the declaration)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf8'?>
<manifest>...</manifest>
```

`updatedxml` later is serialized using `json dumps` before it parsed to a JSON

```
print(json.dumps(updatedxml))
```

and there is a "\n" in the output, any pythonic way to get rid of it?

```
"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf8'?>\n<manifest>...</manifest>"
```

Comment: why do you care about the new line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the reason why this happens is because of the below ElementTree implementation of toString method which internally calls the write method as shown below:

```
def tostring(element, encoding=None, method=None, *, short_empty_elements=True):
  
    stream = io.StringIO() if encoding == 'unicode' else io.BytesIO()
    ElementTree(element).write(stream, encoding, method=method, short_empty_elements=short_empty_elements)
    return stream.getvalue()


def write(self, file_or_filename, encoding=None, xml_declaration=None, default_namespace=None, method=None, *,
    
    if not method:
        method = "xml"
    elif method not in _serialize:
        raise ValueError("unknown method %r" % method)
    if not encoding:
        if method == "c14n":
            encoding = "utf-8"
        else:
            encoding = "us-ascii"
    enc_lower = encoding.lower()
    with _get_writer(file_or_filename, enc_lower) as write:
        if method == "xml" and (xml_declaration or (xml_declaration is None and enc_lower not in ("utf-8", "us-ascii", "unicode"))):
            declared_encoding = encoding
            if enc_lower == "unicode":
                # Retrieve the default encoding for the xml declaration
                import locale
                declared_encoding = locale.getpreferredencoding()
            write("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='%s'?>\n" % (declared_encoding,))
        if method == "text":
            _serialize_text(write, self._root)
        else:
            qnames, namespaces = _namespaces(self._root, default_namespace)
            serialize = _serialize[method]
            serialize(write, self._root, qnames, namespaces, short_empty_elements=short_empty_elements)
```

You can see that the "\n" get written by this **write** method.

The easiest way is to remove the "\n" afterwards.

```
print("".join(json.dumps(updatedxml).split("\\n")))
```

If you only want to replace the first instance of "\n", then do the below:

```
print(json.dumps(updatedxml).replace("\\n", "", 1))
```

Comment: this won't render all json or xml in new lines instead it will take single line

Comment: @ZainUlAbidin Doesn't he need it to be in a single line? I thought he wants to put this xmlstring as a value for some key in a json object.

Comment: @NavaneethSen Yup, you're right. Apart from modifying the serialized string, I am wondering is the newline added by ElementTree is expected at the first place

Comment: @JeffPang i have updated the answer with the reason why you get the "\n" in first place. Hope this helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove all newlines you can just use python's `string.replace()`

```py
print(json.dumps(updatedxml).replace("\n", ""))
```

To remove the newline just before `<manifest>` but retain all others, fetch it's index then exclude that character from the output

```py
dump = json.dumps(updatedxml)
idx = dump.index("\n<manifest>")
print(dump[:idx] + dump[idx+1:])
```

Since you asked for a pythonic way, I supposed you could use list comprehension, though the above is likely both faster and much easier to read.

```py
dump = json.dumps(updatedxml)
print("".join([char for i, char in enumerate(dump) if i != dump.index("\n<manifest>")]))
```